# How to remove silicone keyboard cover residue left on keys?

Tags: keyboard

After using a silicone keyboard cover on my MacBook Air for half a year, it has left shiny stains on it. How can I remove them without damaging the keyboard? I have already tried using isopropyl alcohol, but it didn't help me.

[image: Photo of keyboard]

[image: Photo of silicone cover]

Comment: Did the isopropyl alcohol remove the letters at all?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - not on a Mac keyboard, the letters are embedded plastic, right through the key on laptops, shallower on non-lit keyboards, but not just 'painted on'. - https://i.stack.imgur.com/s54NF.jpg

Comment: Alexander - are you certain it's residue & not just that the keys do eventually go shiny with repeated use? I don't have a worn one right now to photograph, but the non-lit keyboards will eventually get worn enough to start to wear through the letters after about 7-10 years. I just replaced a lot of ours recently so they're all too new to really show it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Certainly worth three times the cost! :)  I jest, but seriously, that is a very nice feature.  On the other hand, white permanent markers are very inexpensive and are handy for many other uses.  Do you know if the embedded plastic is present for the words like "control" and "option" on the Mac keyboards too?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - All the inverse colour is embedded - on the laptops so it illuminates, which it couldn't if it didn't go right through. The desktop keyboards too, but not all the way through, which is why eventually the letters do wear off. I found a really battered old one in the junk room that hasn't gone to recycle yet. See how the most used keys are shiny & quite dished, you can even see fingernail marks on S, E, R & T [also the S is starting to wear out] whereas the Z is almost pristine & still matt finish [if more than a little grubby] https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRcmC.jpg

Comment: BTW, I buy these up in quantity from eBay. You can get them for about £40 these days, which is what they used to retail for. When they stopped making them, the prices soared to £140, but have eased back again. I have simply never used a better keyboard, ever, so I keep a stock in case one gets damaged or eventually wears out. The new wireless ones **are** £140, which I think is ridiculous. Same thing plus a fingerprint sensor  minus a wire ≠ £100 in my mind :\ Though I did pay £90 for a Logitech for my HTPC… & it's not even in the same league - but it has a trackpad I need for sofa surfing.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can't formally ask it on SU because it's a "why" question, but do you know why they didn't make the desktop keyboards like the laptop ones (with the inverse colour going all the way through)?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - maybe they're harder/more expensive to make. I also don't know when they started doing this to be able to check back. I only have ever had one Mac laptop, a 2012, but desktops since 1990. The standard Apple Aluminium Keyboard was first released in 2008, with the Mac Pro range, so a bit of extra expense would be expected. idk when they brought it to lappies. The £90 Logitech, btw, does have the same system, so the backlight shines through the letters, it just *feels* a lot cheaper when typing.

Comment: @Tetsujin This key is not worn out it is 100% silicone cover stain

Comment: Thing is, I don't think it can be. Silicone is almost inert; it doesn't adhere to other surfaces, it's extremely non-stick.

Answer (score 1):

White spirit removed it without residue.